# Checking arrays against one another and either combining if not matched on value, or updating/pushing fi there is a match

Tags: php, arrays, api

I have code where I'm simply calling an API and I've converted it to loop the call so that I can call it with three different argument values. This is because the API is structured where it can accept one value for that argument at a time, but I need to compare the results of the three calls and I think the best way is to build a single array from the responses by either pushing a value if it exists or pushing the whole index if not. Think of it like the API response can give me data that can be as much as 400 products that are sold across 3 stores. All 400 may be sold in one store, but maybe only 120 in another and 100 in the third.

I need my array to be all 400 products but I'll want to have an array within that holds the stores for the  given product.

Code:

```
  $IdentifierTest = 1472;
    $arguments = ['store 1', 'store 2', 'store 3'];
    
    $TestApi = app(TestApi::class);
    $newArray = array();

    foreach($arguments as $argument){
        $testResponse = $TestApi->getData($IdentifierTest, $argument);
        $Data = $testResponse->getResult()->getData(); // get the final results of call
        
        //check if array empty, and if so, push all records
        // if not empty, start checking 'id' against existing array records. If match, push stores. If not, add record to array
        
        if(empty($newArray)){
            array_push($newArray, $Data);
        }else{
            array_push($newArray, $Data);
        }
    }
    

    $this->makeFile($IdentifierTest, $Data);
```

An example of the response is:

```
    array:426 [▼
        0 => prices {#2698 ▼
            #container: array:11 [▼
                    "prd" => 2380
                    "id" => "173489"
                    "price" => "65.00"
            ]
        }
```

The issue is that specific example only shows up when calling the API with 'store 1' and 'store 2' as the argument, but not 'store 3'. What I'd like to do is call the API with each argument and create a new array with a `stores` index that pushes the store number if the id exists in the call, like so:

```
    array:426 [▼
        0 => prices {#2698 ▼
            #container: array:11 [▼
                    "prd" => 2380
                    "id" => "173489"
                    "price" => "65.00"
                    stores: array[
                       'store 1',
                       'store 2'     
                    ]
            ]
        }
```

So when it's called with 'store 1' I would push the response into an array with 'store 1' as the value in 'stores', then on 'store 2' I would take the response and first check to see if the id exists in the array I've made. If it exists, I'll  add 'store 2' to the 'stores' and if not I'll make a new index in the array.

Basically, if product (id) 178293 is sold in all three stores then that means it would come back in all 3 API response calls and would end up being a single record in this new array with `stores['store 1', 'store 2', 'store 3']`

My current code, as far as I've gotten, is simply doing a check on the new array to see if it's empty and if it's not it pushes the whole response (for debugging I also pushed if the array isn't empty, just to make sure all values came in). I am getting all values that way but it's creating three large arrays within one so that's another sticking point.

How can I create a new array from this where I push only the stores if the id exists in the API call while keeping the current structure?

Comment: what if the prices are different at each store?

Comment: The response isn't a single record, it's an array of records, so you shouldn't just push it onto `$newArray`. You should loop over all the records in the response. For each one, check if there's already an item in `$newArray` for that product ID. If there is, push the store name onto its `stores` array, otherwise create one with the current store in the array. It would be easiest if you made `$newArray` an associative array keyed by product ID.

Comment: @Barmar to the first question the prices are always the same no matter what in this instance, it's more a matter of inventory than price

Comment: Why is `array_push($newArray, $Data);` used in both conditional outcomes?  If you are asking how to group rows by a column value and create subarrays from another column, we already have duplicates for that task.

Comment: @Barmar your explanation makes sense, do you have an example of what you would use to check the arrays and then push? I thought about using ```if(array_key_exists)``` at first but that didn't seem to work due to the structure and not allowing me to tell it that 'prd' is the key

Comment: `if (!array_key_exists($item['prd'], $array)) { $array[$item['prd']] = []; }`